# How do we know this is the unique solution to this functional equation?

Tags: functional-equations

I have the functional equation $$F(x)+F(y)=F(\sqrt {x^2+y^2})$$

I know that one solution to this equation is $F(x)=a\cdot x^2$. However, I am told that this is the unique solution, but I don't know how to show this?

**How do we know that this is the unique solution?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing $x$ by $-x$ we see that $F(x)=F(-x)$: $F$ is an even function.
Define $G(u)=F(\sqrt{u})$ for $u\ge0$. Then
$$G(u)+G(v)=F(\sqrt u)+F(\sqrt v)=F(\sqrt{u+v})=G(u+v).$$
This functional equation has the only **continuous** solutions $G(u)=au$.
But it also has non-continuous solutions. As $\Bbb R$ is an infinite-dimensional $\newcommand{\Q}{\Bbb Q}\Q$-vector space, there is a nonzero
$\Q$-linear map $\phi:\Bbb R\to\Q$. Define $F(x)=\phi(x^2)$. Then $F$ is non-continuous and satisfies the functional equation.

The trouble is, that functions like $\phi$ can only be "constructed" by
some form of the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: I wondered why I was struggling so hard to prove that $F$ sends $x$ to $x^2$ for anything other than a set of measure $0$.

Comment: How do we know that it only has thw continuous solution $G(u)=au$?

Comment: From the additivity, one easily gets $G(u)=uG(1)$ for **rational** $u$, so if $G$ is continuous this holds for real $u$ too. @Programmer2134